# High score listing SQL group by error

Tags: sql

I'm listing players in a high score table, but I want to group by Name so it doesnt show multiple results by each player, only their top score.

**My current SQL:**

```
SELECT * FROM leaderboards GROUP BY name ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 5
```

But this isn't showing the TOP score by that player in the listing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT name, MAX(score) FROM leaderboards GROUP BY name ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5
```